# Triple Cross Product Identity for imaginary quaternions $\mathbb{H}_0$

Tags: ring-theory, quaternions, division-ring

Considering $x,y,z \in \mathbb{H}_0$, $x,y,z=\alpha$**i** $+ \beta $**j** $+ \gamma $**k**, prove the Triple Cross Product Identity:
\begin{equation}
(x \times y) \times z = y(x \bullet z) - x(y \bullet z)
\end{equation}
with the cross product defined as usual, and $(\alpha$**i** $+ \beta $**j** $+ \gamma $**k**$)\bullet(\alpha'$**i** $+ \beta' $**j** $+ \gamma' $**k**$)=\alpha\alpha'+\beta\beta'+\gamma\gamma'$.

The proof becomes straightforward if we define wlog $x=\alpha$**i**, $y=\alpha$**i** $+ \beta $**j**, $z=\alpha$**i** $+ \beta $**j** $+ \gamma $**k**, and I need to convert it to the desired form with Gram-Schmidt, but don't know exactly why or how. Any type of help is appreciated.

Comment: This identity has many other names: Lagrange's identity, BAC-CAB, Grassmann identity. Its [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Proof) is straightforward. Why quaternions? Why Gram-Schmidt?

Comment: Because I have to prove it for the imaginary quaternions.

Comment: You could use any "vector" proof of this identity, it makes no difference whether or not you call the "imaginary quaternions" or "vectors". Alternatively, for a more "quaternion" oriented proof, you could use the following identities $$x\times y = \frac12(xy - yx),$$$$x\bullet y = \frac12(xy+yx),$$$$xy = x\bullet y + x\times y.$$ Note that these are only valid when $x,y$ are imaginary.

Comment: But this doesn't reduce the coordinates of any of the vectors :(

Comment: What does "reduce" mean? To be clear: in Nicholas' notation $xy$ is a quaternion multiplication and $\bullet$ and $\times$ are the ordinary scalar and cross product we know from $\mathbb R^3\,.$ We need to see your attempts. Perhaps it is worth mentioning that in Nicholas' last line $x\bullet y$ is the real part of the quaternion $xy$ and the components of $x\times y$ are those of the imaginary part.

Comment: One correction to my comment: I was missing a minus sign, it should be $$x\bullet y = -\frac12(xy + yx),\quad xy = -x\bullet y + x\times y.$$ You don't need to "reduce" any coordinates. You don't need coordinates at all. The only thing you need is to apply the identities I listed; that is enough to prove the triple product identity.

Comment: I appreciate your help, truly, but the main issue with my question is that I am asked to give an explanation to that decomposition and then complete the proof that way.

Comment: Honestly, if you just multiplied two quaternions now you probably see what you have to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using
$$
x=x_1\,\mathbf{i}+x_2\,\mathbf{j}+x_3\,\mathbf{k}\,,\quad y=y_1\,\mathbf{i}+y_2\,\mathbf{j}+y_3\,\mathbf{k}\,,
$$
it is straightforward to show that pure quaternions multiply as
$$
xy=-x\bullet y+(x\times y)\,.
$$
Since $x\bullet y$ is symmetric in $x,y$ and $x\times y$ is anti symmetric
\begin{align}
x\times y&=\frac{xy-yx}{2}\,,\quad x\bullet y=-\frac{xy+yx}{2}\,.
\end{align}
Then, clearly
$$
(x\times y)\times z=\frac{xyz-yxz-zxy+zyx}{4}\,.
$$
The RHS term $(x\bullet z)y-(y\bullet z)x$ is equal to this because it is

> \begin{align}\require{cancel}&-\frac{xz+zx}{2}y+\frac{yz+zy}{2}x\\[2mm]&=-\frac{xz+zx}{4}y+\frac{yz+zy}{4}x-y\frac{xz+zx}{4}+x\frac{yz+zy}{4}\\[2mm]&=\frac{-\cancel{xzy}-zxy+\bcancel{yzx}+zyx-yxz+\bcancel{yzx}+xyz+\cancel{xzy}}{4}\,.\end{align}